# HTML simple layout

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a store site and I need your help to do what I want, see the photo I've attached:

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhax5.png)

I do not know how I can add the list and the buttons there, look at my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <a><img src="images/******.png" alt="Img"><a>
</div>
```

Thanks =)

Comment: I suggest you read some "getting started with html" tutorial. There are _millions_ of those around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="modal-box">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <button class="modal-close">X</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/****" alt="Img" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="fl-right btn-close">Fechar</button>
</div>
```